# to remove operating system selection at the time of booting

Tags: windows-7

I was using ubuntu 11 along with windows 7 home premium (pre-install os is windows) in my friends laptop before using in mine.
Then formated his laptop (c drive format only) and installed windows 7 again, in this process we lost ubuntu.
But now also when system is booted/rebooted it show both the options of os windows7 as well ubuntu.
Why it shows both of the os when ubuntu is not present, and how to remove ubuntu choice to directly boot to windows7.
And also i want to know whether there was any loss of memory in this whole process???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question, looks like it is more about Microsoft Windows than it is about Ubuntu. However, since I have also been a victim of unnecessary grub i'll help you :)

First, let's confirm, you want is to boot Microsoft Windows automatically without seeing list of operating systems on boot right? If so, what you need to do is, insert a Windows 7 Installation DVD to your optical drive (I am assuming you are using Windows 7, if not act according to your version of Microsoft Windows) and boot from DVD. When it boots, select language, keyboard and such and click next.

[image]

On next step, select 'Repair your computer' on the bottom left corner.

[image: repair your computer]

When repair options come up, select 'Startup Reapir'.

[image: Startup Repair]

It may take a few minutes, when it is done computer will reboot and you won't see boot loader menu (grub) again.